# Can a neuron produce electric or magnetic effect?

Tags: neuroscience, brain

According to my view,As a neuron is an electrical impulse generating cell and through this impulse it carries information from brain to whole body or vice-versa, As here a very small electricity is generated so there must be some electrons which can produce an electrical or magnetic effect !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any time charges move (current), electric and magnetic fields are created.

Neurons involve quite small voltages, on the order of 100 mV as well as small currents. Neurons process and transmit information through small changes in voltage, but they generally return to rest. That means, over a long time scale, the net electric and magnetic field is going to be zero: everything averages out to some steady state. Neurons and their fibers are made up of roughly spherical or cylindrical compartments, and voltage is going to be roughly constant within those compartments (because a solution with dissolved ions is a good conductor). That means the changes occur along the edges, and think of a sphere: if the same change occurs all around the entire surface, once you get sufficiently far away you're going to see all those fields as cancelling each other out. For a cylinder, the cancelling will occur in every direction except along the long axis of the cylinder.

That said, populations of neurons that have synchronous activity and are arranged in favorable orientations (like that of [pyramidal cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramidal_cell) in neocortex) can create detectable electrical and magnetic fields. [Electroencephalography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroencephalography) and [magnetoencephalography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetoencephalography) are commonly used techniques to measure this brain activity (electrical and magnetic, respectively) from outside the skull.